# Scriptlet and values for an input box

Tags: javascript, scriptlet

I am using DataTables on a page and am having it fill itself in by collecting data from a spreadsheet. The code currently looks like this:

```
 <tbody>
    <? var stringified1 = getDataJobNumbers(); ?>
    <? var stringified2 = getDataCustomerName();?>
    <? var stringified3 = getDataQuantity();?>
    <? var stringified4 = getDataInsertNumber();?>
    <? var stringified5 = getDataHours();?>
    <? var stringified6 = getDataDriverHours();?>
    <? var stringified7 = getDataDate();?>
     <?var job = JSON.parse(stringified1)?>
     <? var customer = JSON.parse(stringified2)?>
     <? var quantity = JSON.parse(stringified3)?>
     <? var inserts = JSON.parse(stringified4)?>
     <? var hours = JSON.parse(stringified5)?>
     <? var driverHours = JSON.parse(stringified6)?>
     <? var date = JSON.parse(stringified7)?>

        <? for (var i = 0; i < job.length; i++) { ?>
       <tr>
       <td><?= job[i] ?></td>
       <td><?= customer[i] ?></td>
       <td><?= date[i] ?></td>
       <td><?= quantity[i] ?></td>
       <td><?=inserts[i]?></td>
       <td><?= hours[i] ?></td>
       <td><?= driverHours[i] ?></td>
       </tr>

          <? } ?>

    </tbody>
```

Now, what I would like to do is have the inserts, hours, and drive hours actually show up as input boxes. Normally I would do this:

```
<td><input type="text"></td>
```

and leave it at that. But I would like for the any value that might currently be in the spreadsheet to show up as the default value in the input box.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
<td><input type=text value="<?=inserts[i]?>"></td>
```

However, I'm not sure what would. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Scriptlets are still a bit of a gray area in my understanding.

Comment: are you able to retrieve the values in html?

Comment: The problem is the loop. I need to loop through the entire length of the arrays because the lines on the spreadsheet are in constant flux. I'm not sure how to pass the information over to the html when the length of the array will continually be uncertain.

Comment: you don't have the possibility to use JSTL tags?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JSTL, so I was looking into it. The problem there seems to be that the site is built using Google as a platform and so is built using Google Sites and Google Script. I don't seem to have a way to install/host the .jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had a typo...

```
<td><input type="number" value="<?=inserts[i]?>"></td>
```

works just fine.